# Looking for a Powershell way to group multiple dates by week

Tags: powershell, date

I have a CSV file of transactions. I've been looking for a way to group the transactions per week.

I know PowerShell has `Group-Object` and this works to group everything into individual dates, I'm looking to aggregate things by week.

Thanks in advance!

I'm looking at `Transaction Date` and wanting to loop over all rows to group things in "7 day" buckets. As an example, from 8/31 to 8/24, then 8/24 to 8/17, and so on.

Sample CSV:

```
Transaction Date,Posted Date,Card No.,Description,Category,Debit
8/31/2022,9/1/2022,1,Meals on wheels!,a,3.5
8/30/2022,9/1/2022,1,Meals on wheels!,b,3.5
8/30/2022,8/31/2022,1,Meals on wheels!,c,3.5
8/30/2022,8/31/2022,1,Meals on wheels!,a,3.5
8/29/2022,8/31/2022,1,Meals on wheels!,a,3.5
8/29/2022,8/30/2022,1,Meals on wheels!,a,3.5
8/26/2022,8/29/2022,1,Meals on wheels!,b,3.5
8/28/2022,8/29/2022,1,Meals on wheels!,b,3.5
8/27/2022,8/29/2022,1,Meals on wheels!,b,3.5
8/25/2022,8/26/2022,1,Meals on wheels!,b,3.5
8/25/2022,8/26/2022,1,Meals on wheels!,b,3.5
8/23/2022,8/24/2022,1,Meals on wheels!,c,3.5
8/23/2022,8/24/2022,1,Meals on wheels!,c,3.5
8/22/2022,8/23/2022,1,Meals on wheels!,c,3.5
8/21/2022,8/23/2022,1,Meals on wheels!,c,3.5
8/21/2022,8/23/2022,1,Meals on wheels!,a,3.5
8/21/2022,8/22/2022,1,Meals on wheels!,a,3.5
```

Adding something that looks close but I'm not sure about the logic, as it happens the dates in the CSV are in descending order, so `AddDays(-7)` appears to be a step in the right direction.

```
$NextWeekNeeded = $true

$csv | ForEach-Object {

[datetime]$CurrentDay = $PSItem.'Transaction Date'

    IF($NextWeekNeeded){

    write-host -ForegroundColor Cyan 'Next week needed'

    $Week = $CurrentDay.AddDays(-7)

    $WeekInfo = "Week: {0}" -f $Week

    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Yellow $WeekInfo

    $NextWeekNeeded = $false

    #$PSItem

    }

    IF($CurrentDay -ge $Week){

    $PSItem | select 'Transaction Date', Description, Debit

    } Else {

    $NextWeekNeeded = $true

    }

}

}
```

Comment: Can you post a sanitized csv, with a before and after of what's expected?

Comment: @AbrahamZinala of course, I completely overlooked posting a sample CSV.

Answer (score 1):

Ditto to what *'Abraham Zinala'*, said as not having it focus us to guess.

Nonetheless, do you mean something like this:

```
Clear-Host
 @(
'01/01/2022',
'01/01/2022',
'01/02/2022',
'01/03/2022',
'01/03/2022',
'01/03/2022'
) | 
ForEach-Object {((Get-Date($PSItem)).AddDays(7))} | 
Group-Object | 
Select-Object -Property Count, Name

# Results
<#
Count Name              
----- ----              
    2 08-Jan-22 00:00:00
    1 08-Feb-22 00:00:00
    3 08-Mar-22 00:00:00
#>
```